# Equal height CSS columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns

Using [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) example

HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
  <div id="col1">Column 1<br/>2</div>
    <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
    <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    background:red;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    background:yellow;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    background:green;
}
```

There are more complicated demo pages, but I am looking to use the first example for my purposes. Why isn't the example working?

http://jsfiddle.net/YryJM/2/

Comment: The "equal height columns" problem can be solved with flexbox now.

Comment: The exmaple you picked doesn't give equal height columns. The description for it states: > And here is the CSS that forces the container div to the height of the longest column. You will need to use the final version at the end of the blog post to get the effect you are after - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm

Comment: It's unclear what this question is asking, currently. What does "working" mean? Please see [mcve] for more information on what's required for debugging questions.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do equal height columns is with `display: table`.

```
#container1 {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}

#col1, #col2, #col3 {
  display: table-cell;
}
#col1 {
    width:30%;
    background:red;
}
#col2 {
    width:40%;
    background:yellow;
}
#col3 {
    width:30%;
    background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YryJM/3/

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work? by setting a fixed height of the container div and then setting the col divs to 100%?

```
#container1 {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:50px;
}
#col1 {
float:left;
width:30%;
background:red;
height:100%;
 }
#col2 {
float:left;
width:40%;
background:yellow;
height:100%;
}
#col3 {
float:left;
width:30%;
background:green;
height:100%;
}
```

example
http://jsfiddle.net/squinny/dps4f/1/

idk if this will help you or not?