# css3 flexbox compatibility problems with Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to sort out my flexbox layout so it is compatible with latest versions of IE/Firefox/Safari, and I have issues with Firefox/Safari.

Proposed layout:

```
-----------------
     header
-----------------
    |
    |
    |
nav |  section
    |
    |
    |
    |
```

In Firefox and Safari `<section>` is underneath `nav`

CSS:

```
body {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flexbox;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

header {
    padding-top:100px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
    -moz-flex: 1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 1 100%;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

nav {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
}

section {
    -webkit-flex: 4;
    -moz-flex: 4;
    -ms-flex: 4;
    flex: 4;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, this:

```
body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flexbox;
}
```

Should be this:

```
body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) { /* hide from the incomplete Flexbox implementation in Firefox */
    body {
      display: flex;
    }
}
```

This doesn't do anything because IE doesn't have an implementation of the 2009 Flexbox draft:

```
body {
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
}
```

You've also added the moz prefix on the properties from the standard Flexbox draft, but Firefox implemented those prefix free (only the 2009 properties should have a moz prefix).

Even if you fix all of these things, it still won't work in Safari or Firefox.  Why?

- Until iOS7 comes out, Safari only has an implementation of the 2009 Flexbox draft.  It fails to implement `box-lines: multiple`, which is what enables wrapping in that draft
- Firefox has an implementation for the 2009 draft *and* the standard draft, but neither implementation supports wrapping.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How would you recommend I dealt with Firefox/Safari? Polyfills?

Comment: Honestly, I recommend not using Flexbox for layout.  Windows XP is too prominent of an OS (it's #2 in popularity) and they can't upgrade beyond IE8.  If you still wish to use Flexbox anyway, then you have to group nav and section together with an extra flex container and do away with wrapping (see: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/rifzt).

Comment: If I were to move away from Flexbox, should I just use normal table markup?

Comment: Why would you use a table?  Tables are for tabular data, not layout.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220687/1652962