# CSS browser prefixes not rendering on browsers other than Chrome

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

I have a site (homepage for now) for which I have used the necessary browser prefixes. Just to be sure I've also added -prefix-free to the head. But Chrome is the only browser that renders the site in the intended styles. In all other browsers, elements are askew and out of place. What could be the matter? Why are the other browsers not rendering the styles inspite of prefixes?

Have shared the css in **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c9fomgc/)**.
Following is an extract:

```
.event3 {
     -webkit-box-flex: 1;
     -webkit-flex: 1;
         -ms-flex: 1;
             flex: 1;   

}
```

Comment: Provide a working fiddle. Your fiddle only adds the css. Your code is specific -webkit- browsers, so  I can't figure out why. Ask a correct question and you'll obtain better and faster answers

Comment: ok - just give me a minute

Comment: @Marcos https://jsfiddle.net/8c9fomgc/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css3 flexbox compatibility problems with Firefox and Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473983/css3-flexbox-compatibility-problems-with-firefox-and-safari)