# Make two overlapping divs show and hide on mousehover

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS and HTML to show and hide a menu div when the user hovers the mouse over the right edge of the screen. This is what I want:

- An arrow is shown on the right side of the screen. If the user hovers over the arrow or the vertical box surrounding it, the arrow disappears and the menu with four buttons is shown. If the user leaves the vertical box, the four buttons disappear and the arrow returns.

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work. I tried having two separate divs for the menu buttons and for an invisible box with the arrow centered. This didn't work as the invisble box made the buttons underneath unclickable. We tried to solve this with the Z-index, that didn't work.

I'm now trying to fix it with having all buttons in the same div but with different classes, this isn't working for me. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="east-exit">
  <a><i class="communicate-icon fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
  <a><i class="communicate-icon fa fa-comments"></i></a>
  <i class="east-exit-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
  <a><i class="communicate-icon fa fa-phone"></i></a>
  <a><i class="communicate-icon fa fa-camera"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#east-exit {
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.east-exit-icon {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.communicate-icon {
  display: none;
}

#east-exit:hover + .communicate-icon {
  display: flex;
}

#east-exit:hover + .east-exit-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/453/

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the adjacent sibling selector `+` (since you're not interested in siblings but rather **children**)

```
#east-exit:hover .communicate-icon {
  display: flex;
}

#east-exit:hover .east-exit-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/454/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so close :P

Comment: you need to prefix for moz

Comment: @Mayia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473983/css3-flexbox-compatibility-problems-with-firefox-and-safari